# Parsing column-based ASCII data in C

Tags: c, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse text that contains integers in a fixed number of columns. For example, my input file might look like:

```
=1=2=3
=4=5=6
=8=910
```

where the `=` sign represents spaces in the input. *The equals sign isn't in the input file; I just put it there for illustrative purposes.* Each integer is contained in two columns without zero padding, so the third line is not a typo: it is 8, 9, and then 10.

The standard `sscanf` does not work since it eliminates spaces first and then applies the format string. For example, I tried:

```
sscanf(buf, "%2d%2d%2d", &int1, &int2, &int3)
```

but it ends up parsing the third line as 8, 91, and 0.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to pulling out the data column by column manually?

Comment: A custom format that a system I'm interfacing with is generating. Can't control it, unfortunately :/

Comment: you shouldn't assume that you have 3 numbers with `"%2d%2d%2d"`.

Comment: If you don't mind me saying, that's a terrible format. I think you're going to have to do it column by column. Have you tried replacing all the '='s with '0's before doing the `sscanf()`?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that the equal signs aren't actually in the input. Sorry about that.

Comment: @madper: The input is guaranteed to have three ints. Also, I check the result of scanf to ensure I read the correct number of inputs.

Comment: Sounds like you're reading the IERS "finals.all" file. I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many different ways. Using `sscanf` (or `strtol`), you have (at least) these two options:

- Make a copy of the column and then `sscanf` it:

  ```
  char temp[COL_SIZE+1] = {'\0'};  /* last character will always be NUL */
  for (i = 0; i < col_count; ++i)
  {
      memcpy(temp, buf + i * COL_SIZE, COL_SIZE * sizeof(*buf)); /* "* sizeof" actually unnecessary */
      sscanf(temp, "%d", &num[i]); /* or use strtol */
  }
  ```
- You can also do it a bit more efficient, given that you will not do this on a constant string **specially never on a string literal**:

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < col_count; ++i)
  {
      char temp;
      int column_beg = i * COL_SIZE;
      int column_end = column_beg + COL_SIZE;
      temp = buf[column_end];
      buf[column_end] = '\0';
      sscanf(buf + column_beg, "%d", &num[i]); /* or use strtol */
      buf[column_end] = temp;
  }
  ```

  What it does is to insert a `'\0'` after each column, read it, then restore the original character. If done on a string literal, this will be undefined behavior.

I personally recommend the first method.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid the copy but it looks like I'll have to do that.

Comment: If you reverse the order of the loop in the second example, (`i = col_count -1; i >=0; --i`) you don't need to save/restore the original character.

Comment: @DavidGelhar, that's true. If the OP doesn't care about the buffer being destroyed, he can certainly do that. I usually tend to not use backward `for`s, though, because if `i` is changed to `unsigned` you get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it character by character:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int val;
  char input[] = "=8=910";
  char *p = input;

  while (*p) {
    val = 0;
    if (isdigit((unsigned char)*p)) val = *p - '0'; // 1st digit
    p++;
    val *= 10;                                      // 2nd
    val += *p++ - '0';                              // digit
    printf("val: %d\n", val);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you reimplementing `sscanf` with `%d`?

Comment: Just calculating values from two digits at a time without copying or reading the same digit more than once.

Comment: @Shahbaz: No, he's taking the "consume leading whitespace" behaviour out of the equation.

Comment: Your solutions is very limited and un-extendable . What if column size changed from 2 to 3? What if column size was given in input? What if the numbers in the file were changed to hexadecimal? What if that was configurable? You are reinventing the wheel and that's not good advice.

Comment: You can easily transform the program above into a function that does basically the same thing and has as many parameters as you like: column width, accepted charset, error function, conversion function, ..., ...

Comment: sometimes its a one time do/forget operation. I like the way you handled it, upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You could use `scanf()` and the `"%2c"` conversion specifier to read in two characters into a properly zero-terminated array, then convert that to decimal (with `strtol()` or something like that)... but that's butt-ugly. Then again, not uglier than the format itself.

Generally speaking, `*scanf()` is a very poor choice for parsing input, because of it's somewhat touchy behaviour if the input is malformed. You are probably better off, in the long run, to read the file into an internal buffer and do your own custom parsing / error handling.

Comment: What happens to `'\n'` in your solution? Also, the OP is not using `scanf`, but indeed `sscanf` on a buffer.

Comment: I didn't mention `\n`, because I only gave a hint, not a solution - because the OP might have copy & pasted that, ignoring my *other* hint that `scanf()` (and `fscanf()` and `sscanf()` and all other `*scanf()`'s) are not really that great for parsing input. Added the `*` to make it clear I meant the whole function family.

Comment: Actually `sscanf` is a wonderful function. `scanf` is said to be bad because you can't revert the input in case of parse error, but `sscanf` is widely used.

Comment: @Shahbaz: `*scanf()` does not tell you where exactly it failed, or what caused the failure. It just tells you how many conversions were successful. That is true for `sscanf()` just as well, and makes for really dumb error messages like "parsing failed, check input".

Answer (score 0):

Without using `scanf`. Should be fast...

```
void parse_columns(const char *line)
    {
    char buf[3];
    buf[2] = '\0';

    int i = 0;
    for (const char *c = &line[0]; *c; c++, i++)
        {
        buf[i] = *c;
        if (1 == i)
            {
            printf("%d\n", atoi(buf));
            i = -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If "fast" is what you're looking for, you should find a way around the `printf( atoi() )`...